# Why does recyclerview ScrollToBottom is not working efficiently?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I thoroughly searched nd tried to implement diff diff things, but it seems not possible,

Requirement:
In my chat app, when I open particular user chat screen

1. It should be scrolled to bottom so that user can see last msg/conversation
2. When any new msg/new item will add at that time it should scroll to bottom

**Please note, if I'll use below methods then my 1st requirement is not working**

```
private void loadMessages() {
        try {
            DatabaseReference messageReference = rootReference.child(MESSAGES).child(currentUId).child(chatUser);
            Query query = messageReference.orderByChild(TIME);

            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    messagesList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        try {
                            Messages messages = ds.getValue(Messages.class);
                            messagesList.add(messages);
                            setAdapter();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    databaseError.getMessage();
                }
            };
            query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private void setAdapter() {
        try {
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(binding.recyclerViewLayout.recyclerView, null, messagesList.size());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, messagesList);
                mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
                mLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
                binding.recyclerViewLayout.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                binding.recyclerViewLayout.recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                binding.recyclerViewLayout.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**And if I'll use below method, then my 2nd requirement is not working!**

```
private void loadMessages() {
            try {
                DatabaseReference messageReference = rootReference.child(MESSAGES).child(currentUId).child(chatUser);
                Query query = messageReference.orderByChild(TIME);
    
                ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        messagesList.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            try {
                                Messages messages = ds.getValue(Messages.class);
                                messagesList.add(messages);
                                Comparator<Messages> compare = Collections.reverseOrder();
                                Collections.sort(messagesList, compare);
                                setAdapter();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        databaseError.getMessage();
                    }
                };
                query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    
        private void setAdapter() {
            try {
                if (mAdapter != null) {
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, messagesList);
                    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
                    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
                    mLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
                    binding.recyclerViewLayout.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    binding.recyclerViewLayout.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                    binding.recyclerViewLayout.recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    binding.recyclerViewLayout.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Please pay attention on `setAdapter()` as it is calling on for each loop, first time it is creating adapter and after that immediately with the next increment of loop, it calls notifydatasetchanged.

**EDIT:**

**Complete code:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/11W8jL4_c9vVxVjZM9xBXo4KzH5LFViUn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is very bad practice to wrap all your code in try/catch. This hides fatal issues with the app. Please remove these and run the app to see if it is crashing from a bad reference

Comment: @JacobKaddoura Dear I checked, it is not crashing. And I'll remove it. Can you please tell me the solution?

Comment: @JacobKaddoura I'm waiting. Have you got any solution?

Comment: remove Try catch block + use 
`notifyDataSetChanged()`  only when it's needed because in your code you looping through the snapshot and repeating `notifyDataSetChanged()` over and over again 

suggestion: 
first, try to save the data into some cache or temporary data structure (or you can use builder pattern) and then call 
`setAdapter()`

Comment: @Ali Have you checked my updated question?

Comment: @Ali Please help

Comment: @SychiSingh yes II have read your updated question dear. Let me check it in detail.

Comment: @Ali Fine Ali, I'll wait for the response.

Comment: I am trying to diagnose the problem right now.

Comment: please try the updated code. I hope it will help because I've added a runnable thread on `smoothScrollToPosition()` try it and let me know, And also remove extra parentheses as well.  :D

Comment: @Ali Hey!! I implemented code, but still same problem!

Comment: @Ali https://drive.google.com/file/d/11W8jL4_c9vVxVjZM9xBXo4KzH5LFViUn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JacobKaddoura https://drive.google.com/file/d/11W8jL4_c9vVxVjZM9xBXo4KzH5LFViUn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SychiSingh https://drive.google.com/file/d/16ntS9chGL9RNaoMcZ_hzw2zfJ9DR1V1P/view?usp=sharing

Comment: On my side, it's working fine. on both emulator and phone.

Comment: @Ali Okay, I watch the video: I think I'm not able to explain my problem to you properly. 1st: When you run the app and once UI will visible, that time you observe, you need to little bit scroll to see the last message, but in whatsapp it's not like that. 2nd: when you open keyboard that time some messages hides behind keyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220738/discussion-between-ali-and-sychi-singh).

Comment: @Ali Thank you very very, it is working perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 4:**

1. Got it working (by adding a function `addItem()` in **Adapter**,  `notifyItemInserted(messagesList.size());` in `addItem()` function
2. Added `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);` right after populating the `List<Messages>`

3.After every `sendButtonClickEvent()` added `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);`

**NOTE**: The complete code is in the link given below.

**MainActivity**

```
package studio.devcode.recyclerviewdemo;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import studio.devcode.recyclerviewdemo.MessageAdapter;
import studio.devcode.recyclerviewdemo.Messages;
import studio.devcode.recyclerviewdemo.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageViewSend;
    private EditText editTextMessage;
    private List<Messages> messagesList;
    private MessageAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_layout);
        messagesList = new ArrayList<>();

        imageViewSend = findViewById(R.id.send);
        editTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.type_message);

        setData("12345", "abc");
        setData("12345", "hello");
        setData("123145", "you");
        setData("12345", "there");
        setData("121345", "aqqqbc");
        setData("123145", "abqqc");
        setData("123145", "aqqbc");
        setData("12345", "awwbc");
        setData("123145", "eeabc");
        setData("12345", "abeeec");
        setData("112345", "addbc");
        setData("12345", "abdcc");
        setData("112345", "abccc");
        setData("121345", "abccc");
        setData("12345", "abccc");
        setAdapter();

        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        onSendButtonClick();
        onSoftInputKeyboardOpen();
    }

    private void setData(String from, String message) {
        messagesList.add(new Messages(message, "text", from));
    }


    private void onSendButtonClick(){
        imageViewSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!editTextMessage.getText().toString().isEmpty() || !editTextMessage.getText().toString().equals(" ")){
                    mAdapter.addItem(new Messages(editTextMessage.getText().toString().toUpperCase(), "text", "Ali"));
                    editTextMessage.setText("");
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void setAdapter() {
        try {
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount());


            } else {
                mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, messagesList, "12345");
                mLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
                mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void onSoftInputKeyboardOpen(){
        recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onLayoutChange(View v,
                                        int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                        int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                 if (bottom < oldBottom) {
                     recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(
                                     recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
                         }
                     }, 100);
                 }
             }
         });
    }
}
```

**Messages**

```
package studio.devcode.recyclerviewdemo;

public class Messages {
    private String message;
    private String type;
    private String from;
    private long time;
    private boolean seen;

    public Messages(String message,String type,String from) {
        this.message = message;
        this.from = from;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
}
```

**MessageAdapter**

```
package studio.devcode.recyclerviewdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;



import java.util.List;



public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Messages> messagesList;
    private String currentUid;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Messages> messagesList, String currentUid) {
        try {
            this.currentUid = currentUid;
            this.messagesList = messagesList;
            this.context = context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = null;
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder;
        try {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.message_single_layout, parent, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    protected void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), msg);
    }

    protected boolean checkNull(String data) {
        return data != null && (!data.isEmpty());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            Messages messages = messagesList.get(position);
            if (messages != null) {
                String messageType = messages.getType();
                if (checkNull(messages.getFrom()) && messages.getFrom().equals(currentUid)) {
                    if (checkNull(messageType) && messageType.equals("text")) {
                        holder.chatText_1.setText(messages.getMessage());
                        holder.messageSingleLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.messageSingleLayout_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (checkNull(messageType) && messageType.equals("text")) {
                        holder.chatText.setText(messages.getMessage());
                        holder.messageSingleLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.messageSingleLayout_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messagesList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView chatText, chatText_1, chatTime, chatTime_1;
        public LinearLayout messageSingleLayout, messageSingleLayout_1;
        private final ImageView fileDownload;
        private final ImageView fileDownload_1;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            chatText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatText);
            chatText_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatText_1);
            chatTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatTime);
            chatTime_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatTime_1);
            messageSingleLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageSingleLayout);
            messageSingleLayout_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageSingleLayout_1);
            fileDownload = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fileDownload);
            fileDownload_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fileDownload_1);

        }
    }

    public void addItem(Messages message) {
        messagesList.add(message);
        notifyItemInserted(messagesList.size());
    }


}
```

Please give a star and also follow on GitHub :D

[Github Repo to complete Demo](https://github.com/AafaaqAli/RecyclerViewDemo)

[Vido URL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEfZ2zcfEWfyuoo3CsoHVMsnWmwSfEfE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for reply.. As per your suggestions, I change the code and checked but still same problem. I edited the question and added the code, please check. And regarding try/catch [Thanks for suggestion, I didn't knew about that], I'll remove from everywhere while release the APK.

Comment: your welcome @SychiSingh, let me look into it I hope I will come up with some improvements.

Comment: @SychiSingh can you please add a snippet of RecyclerViewAdapter?

Comment: just a quick suggestion. if you are attaching `onClickListene()` in adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` then its really bad for performance as well, because you are attaching `onClickListener()` on every item even none of the item's `onClickListener()` is being consumed.

Comment: I'm not using onClickListener() anywhere. Also please see the edited question for code snippet.

Comment: @SychiSingh do you have Github repo for the project? that's the last resort.

Comment: let me create a demo for you, give 10 min!!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11W8jL4_c9vVxVjZM9xBXo4KzH5LFViUn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SychiSingh I've updated the solution and its working fine now. have a look

Comment: lemme check Ali

Comment: @SychiSingh, got it, ping me if any other problem persists!

Comment: Just wait, actually in my case data is coming from firebase, so after debugging I got to know that adapter is called first and data is still loading, that's why problem persists. So now, I'm adding a listener inside for loop , and checking that if all data will load then only listener will call and in callback, I'll set adapter. Doint that right now, let's see!

Comment: your welcome @SychiSingh ping me if you need any other help :)

Comment: Umm, actually I need. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660488/how-does-one-can-generate-hash-who-doesnt-know-server-side-coding-and-only-know?noredirect=1#comment112600189_63660488        | [Read the comments as well on that question]

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it soon. give me some time

Comment: Okay sure Ali...Thanks dear

Comment: Umm.. I need help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63799302/how-to-change-payus-dependency-activity-toolbar-background-color-in-android-jav/63799754#63799754